# How to have each Font Awesome icon be a different color?

Tags: tumblr

On my tumblr blog over [here](http://coreiisms.tumblr.com), I use [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) to make all of my page links an icon instead of a text link. All of the icons are filed under the italics class, which I have set to red. However, I would prefer to style them each in a different color. Is there anyway I can do this?

Here's all the relevant code in case you need it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> [ I believe this is just to tell the code where font awesome comes from. ]

<i class="{text:font awesome}"></i></a> [ embedding the icons. ]

i, em {
color:{color:italic};
font-size:17px;
font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 17px #cc0000;
} [ My italics class ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You have to write your own css, but each icon will have a unique class. Add the rules for each icon to the style tags inside the top of your template.

```
.fa-facebook {
   color:#FFCC00;
}

.fa-twitter {
   color:#EC0000;
}
```

And so on.

**EDIT**

Or are you talking about different instances of the same class/icon?

If so you would have to use css 3 selectors for that. Like so:

```
.fa-heart:nth-child(1) {
    color:#FFCC00;
}
.fa-heart:nth-child(2) {
    color:#FF0099;
}
.fa-heart:nth-child(3) {
    color:#EC0000;
}
```

And so on.

More info on nth-child selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

That is assuming they all share the same parent element.

**UPDATE**

Based on your html structure you would need to write your css like this:

```
#links div:nth-child(1) a i {
    color:red;
}

#links div:nth-child(2) a i {
    color:#FFCC00;
}

#links div:nth-child(3) a i {
    color:#0099AA;
}
```

etc. In this case `#links` is the parent and you have wrapped each anchor in a div element, so you have to target the nth-child of `#links` which are divs.

Hope that makes sense. There is a fiddle here with your code working: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/7ov1u1ys/

Comment: Thank you! So,If I add the CSS you mentioned above about the different instances/same icon and want to implement it into a code like this:  

        **<div id="links">  

<a href="/" title="home"><i class="{text:font awesome}"></i></a>
<a href="#?w=500" rel="box1" class="poplight" title="ask"><i class=">{text:font awesome}"></i></a>    
<a href="#?w=500" rel="box2" class="poplight" title="submit"><i>class="{text:font awesome}"></i></a>
<a href="#?w=250" rel="box3" class="poplight" title="navigation"><i>class="{text:font awesome}"></i></a>**  

How could I set each one with nth?